# Meteor: No se reciben notificaciones push con la app cerrada en android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, meteor

Estoy empezando con Meteor.

Actualmente estoy experimentando con la integración con Cordova, concretamente con las notificaciones push a través del plugin raix:push para Meteor.

La aplicación recibe notificaciones push simples cuando está ejecutándose en segundo plano, aunque no he conseguido recibir notificaciones con foto.

El problema es que cuando la app esta completamente cerrada no es capaz de recibir las notificaciones, aunque el servidor no avisa de ningún problema.

La aplicación está desplegada en Heroku.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% mobile-config.js  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

App.configurePlugin('phonegap-plugin-push', {
  SENDER_ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
});


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% client/main.js %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Push.Configure({
 android: {
  senderID: XXXXXXXXXXX,
  alert: true,
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
  vibrate: true,
  clearNotifications: true
  // icon: '',
  // iconColor: ''
 },
});

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
 // counter starts at 0
 this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
   return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
 'click button'(event, instance) {
   // increment the counter when button is clicked
   instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
 },

});

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% server/main.js %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
 // code to run on server at startup

 Push.Configure({
  gcm: {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
  production: true,
 });

});

Meteor.methods({
 sendPush: function() {
  return Push.send({
   from: 'Test',
      title:'Saludo',
      text:'¡hola mundo!',
      badge: 3,
      query: {},
    });
   },
});
```

El mensaje se envía a través de la consola del navegador utilizando

```
> Meteor.call('sendPush');
```

Las versiones instaladas son las siguientes

```
// Meteor@1.4.3.1
// raix:push@3.0.2
// cordova-plugin-device@1.1.4
// phonegap-plugin-push@1.9.4
```

No entiendo lo que me está pasando y llevo bastante tiempo indagando sobre ello sin resultado, cualquier ayuda será bienvenida

Comment: Tal vez tu solución no esté en el backend sino en el aplicativo móvil. Intenta añadiendo en tu función de notificación.. `notificacion.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ¿dónde debería añadir ese código en Meteor?

Comment: No es el backend sino en la aplicación móvil, en este caso SO Android